# Does aws cli long running command affects new files created after the command issue time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Let's say I run the following command at time 10 am UTC.

```
aws s3 mv s3://bucket/folder1 s3://bucket/folder2 --recursive
```

The command runs until 11:45 am UTC.
What I want to understand is, if a file was created at 10:30 am UTC, will it also be moved to the new location by the above command. Please help with the relevant documentation links as well if it's documented somewhere.

Comment: It may or may not be moved to the new location. What `mv` does behind the scene is that it iteratively lists the objects under `folder1` prefix and then perform the copy and delete action. If your newly added object is not included in the listObject response, then it will not be moved to the destination.

Comment: So, I remember listObject supports max keys option. Does it also order the objects something by default like created time? If so, what's the order? If it is created time and it does do it from latest to first, then I don't need to worry about the files added in between getting moved